# Does Photoshop CS6 have Glyphs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, glyphs

I just purchased a font and now they are saying I need to go to Illustrator and go to my "glyphs" to get the "extras" of the font.... well I dont have Illustrator... nor do I know wth glyphs are?!

Anyone know if ps6 has glyphs? the font is purchased was: https://creativemarket.com/L_Worthington/12122-Charcuterie-Cursive

Comment: CC has a glyph panel, CS6 does not.

Answer (score 7):

A "glyph" is merely the term for a specific character in a font file.

Photoshop, unlike other Adobe applications, has no Glyph panel. While it can display and utilize glyphs if they are present, there is no way to access a specific glyph from within Photoshop.

Both Illustrator and InDesign have Glyph Panels which allow you to see and access all glyphs present in a font.

**So the short answer.... Photoshop has no way to access glyphs.**

[image: glyphs]

**There are also many freeware/shareware apps which can show the glyphs in a font file.** To utilize a specific glyph in Photoshop, you need to find an app, any app, that allows you to see the glyphs. Then simply **copy/paste the glyph from that app to Photoshop.**

You may already possess an app capable of showing the glyphs. For example, you can use `Insert > Symbol` in **MicrosoftWord** to view the glyphs in a font. Word simply refers to them as "Symbols". Then copy/paste the one you want into Photoshop.

Answer (score 4):

As stated, there is no Glyphs menu in Photoshop.
However, there are OS system tools you can use to get these characters out of a font file.

Windows has a Character Map utility that you can use to copy right from that program, into a text box within Photoshop. To access the Character map you go to...
**Start > All Programs > Accessories > System Tools:**

[image]

And [**here is a link**](http://fsymbols.com/character-maps/mac/) to how to access the equivalent  on a Mac.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I believe that this only works for glyphs encoded with a Unicode value.  Unencoded glyphs won't show up in Windows, and depending on the version won't show up in Mac.  http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/glyphs_panel_for_the_love_of_god

Answer (score 2):

If using a Mac, the easiest way to find the glyph you require is to use the application **Font Book** (included in the standard installation of OSX)

Choose **View > Repertoire** from the application menu and select the font to display all characters included.

Click to select any of the displayed glyphs and copy/paste back into Photoshop

[image: Font Book screenshot]